# Node crashes when a duplicate data is inserted into mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

So I was trying to test my node server if it can handle insertion of duplicate data to mongodb and apparently it can't.

Here's the code:

```
    app.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password, firstName, lastName} = req.body
    console.log(lastName)
    console.log(typeof(lastName))
    pword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10)
    try {
        const response = user.create({
            email: email,
            password: pword,
            firstName: firstName,
            lastName: lastName
        })

        console.log("User created successfully: " + response)
    } catch (error) {
        return res.json({ status: 'error'})
    }
})
```

and here's the error:

```
MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: ApartmentDB.UserData index: email_1 dup key: { email: "asdasa" }
    at C:\Users\Hans\Desktop\MobDev Final Project\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\insert.js:51:33
    at C:\Users\Hans\Desktop\MobDev Final Project\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection_pool.js:272:25
    at handleOperationResult (C:\Users\Hans\Desktop\MobDev Final Project\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\server.js:370:9)
    at MessageStream.messageHandler (C:\Users\Hans\Desktop\MobDev Final Project\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:479:9)
    at MessageStream.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at processIncomingData (C:\Users\Hans\Desktop\MobDev Final Project\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:108:16)
    at MessageStream._write (C:\Users\Hans\Desktop\MobDev Final Project\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:28:9)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:389:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:330:10)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:334:10) {
  index: 0,
  code: 11000,
  keyPattern: { email: 1 },
  keyValue: { email: 'asdasa' }
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I saw a similar post to mine saying that he was sending two responses, but I don't see that in my case

Comment: We can't tell that without seeing the code of your user model. Though, in general, the error says that the email you are trying to create a user with already exists in your collection, and that is not a bug, practically, there can't be 2 users with the same email in a user database.

Comment: @hacKaTun3s yes, it already exists, but the issue is that the node server is crashing when a duplicate entry exists. Obviously it will be impossible to restart the server everytime a user makes a duplicate entry.

Comment: Model.create is asynchronous, should that be awaited when assigning to a variable?

Comment: @Joe you got a point...

Comment: Does having await enter into the try catch block?
And since the res is sent already the try catch closes and the error crashes the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have not used `await user.create`.

before completing the DB insert operation you are returning response and later DB is throwing an error.

```
app.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password, firstName, lastName } = req.body;
  console.log(lastName);
  console.log(typeof lastName);
  pword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
  try {
    const response = await user.create({
      email: email,
      password: pword,
      firstName: firstName,
      lastName: lastName,
    });

    console.log("User created successfully: " + response);
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.status === "E11000") { // it could be .status, .code etc.. not sure
      return res.json({ status: "error", msg: "User already exist." });
    }
    return res.json({ status: "error" });
  }
});
```

Comment: The error will still persist - Because it is still trying to add a new user with the email of an existing one.

Comment: what you have to do is check the status code of error and return a meaningful msg.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is only to add a check in your handler, like so:

```js
app.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password, firstName, lastName } = req.body;
  console.log(lastName);
  console.log(typeof lastName);
  pword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

  const existingUser = user.findOne({ email });

  if (existingUser) return res.send("User already exists");

  try {
    const response = await user.create({
      email: email,
      password: pword,
      firstName: firstName,
      lastName: lastName,
    });

    console.log("User created successfully: " + response);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.json({ status: "error" });
  }
});
```

Also note that once you add the user you are only `console.log()`ing the data and not sending any response which will only end up throwing a timeout on your client side.

Answer (score 0):

just return a statuscode and a message after checking if user already exists . This will ensure the process doesnot move forward and doesnot try to create a new user with those existing details like this:
if (existingUser) return res.send("User already exists");

Comment: The issue was with interface asynchronicity, which was answered by others, both in look-first and fail-gracefully form.